# I cannot log in to Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, stackexchange.com

Every time I attempt to log in to Stack Exchange (to change my email) I get a screen with a panda under a slide saying that something went wrong. I do not have this problem when I try to login to other Stack Exchange websites like Stack Overflow and *[Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

If I try to log in from another open ID provider (Facebook, Google) the website simply redirects me back to the home page while not being logged in. I started having problems logging in after I had setup my Facebook OpenID.

Comment: Not sure if you already saw my answer earlier, but I just edited it to add a bit more info, so please check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short version of what's happening here is that you have two different accounts. One of them only has the FB credential, the other has email/password. As you're adding the FB credential, we're attempting to merge those accounts - but the merge is failing due to a bug. A fix is out in production now.

Having said all that... have you noticed that you're logging into two different accounts? Try it out - open up an incognito window or a different browser and use your Facebook credentials on Stack Overflow. Click your avatar in the top bar and note the username, rep, etc. Now log out (or open another browser) and log in with your email + password. Do you end up in the same profile as before or another one?

If they're different (as I expect they would be), you can request a merge through the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). This should also fix your ability to log into stackexchange.com.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. I merged my accounts and BAM! it worked! Thank you Mr.Lear